# Node JS Configuration

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am trying configure my node js to run my html code.I am using bootstrap and Express Js also.When I run node js its not loading the css.Can anyone help me what could be the issue.Here is the node js code snippet.

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html')
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

When I directly load the HTML files it loads the CSS properly but when i use node js to load it it fails.What could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: You shouldn't have `app.use()` calls inside of a `app.get()` handler. Put it outside.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.I tried what you have suggested but still i am facing the same issue.Can you please tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect what you've tried.

Comment: I have edited the Question to reflect what i tried Can you please tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: What happens when you try to load the css file directly in your browser?

Comment: @bloodyknuckles When we try to load directly css file it says cant get the file.What could be the issue?Cannot GET /public/stylesheets/home.css.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am using localhost:3000/public/stylesheets/home.css.

Comment: Drop the "/public" from your css URL path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I did as you suggested but still the issue is there. :(http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/home.css)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your directory structure is correct and that you have given the correct permission for Node.js to enter the directories and read the file.

If your directory structure looks like this:

```
/public
    /stylesheets
        home.css
home.html
server.js
```

And your server.js code looks like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen('3000', function() { 
    console.log("Listening on port 3000"); 
});
```

When you run this:

```
node ./server.js
```

And visit this URL in your browser:

http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/home.css

You will get your home.css file returned.

Comment: `app.listen('3000',function(){
  console.log("listening at 3000");
});
`

Answer (score 3):

In express js project to configuration database

```
/config
  /database.js
/server.js
/.env

const http = require('http');
const app = require('express')();
require('./config/database.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.ServerPort, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  logger.info(`Express server listening on port ${process.env.ServerPort}`);
});
```

When you run this:

```
node server.js
```

database.js file

```
const My = require('jm-ez-mysql');

// Init DB Connection
const connection = My.init({
  host: process.env.DBHOST,
  user: process.env.DBUSER,
  password: process.env.DBPASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
  dateStrings: true,
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
  timezone: 'utc',
  multipleStatements: true,
  connectTimeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
  acquireTimeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
  timeout: 100 * 60 * 1000,
});

module.exports = {
  connection,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In express js project, as require you can place you static file.

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory from the /static path prefix.

http://localhost:3000/static/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/static/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/static/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/static/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/static/hello.html
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
check this link for how you can connect your static files with express js